# Can I fail the current transaction from within a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE trigtest(a INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, b INT)
```

I currently have

```
CREATE TRIGGER MaxDelete ON trigtest INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
IF @@rowcount < 1000
DELETE trigtest  WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM deleted)
```

However, it requires me to write the last line in a customized manner for every table I apply it to

Instead of the above, is it possible to write something of the sort:

```
IF @@rowcount > 1000 (OR SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED)
Kill statement
ELSE
Continue statement
```

Comment: Did you try `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;`?

Comment: Just tried on your suggestion and it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  ... continue ...
END
```